# Prettify numbers to their closest number with zeros at the end in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

I have some chunks as following example:

```
// lowest and highest values of chunk arrays
[
    [0, 945710.3843175517],
    [945710.3843175517, 2268727.9557668166],
    [2268727.9557668166, 14965451.25314727],
    [14965451.25314727, 17890252.39415521],
    [17890252.39415521, 3501296406.880383]
]
```

what I want to get from these chunks is something like this:

```
< 1.000.000
1.000.000 - 3.000.000
3.000.000 - 15.000.000
15.000.000 - 18.000.000
> 10.000.000
```

I will use these new numbers as a legend of an informative map.

I use a function to achieve this goal named as `roundClosestLegendNumber` for each value.

All numbers are positive numbers and there is no maximum limitation.

```
roundClosestLegendNumber(5) \\ should give 10
roundClosestLegendNumber(94) \\ should give 100
roundClosestLegendNumber(125) \\ should give 200
roundClosestLegendNumber(945710.3843175517) \\ should give 1000000 
roundClosestLegendNumber(14965451.25314727) \\ should give 15000000
roundClosestLegendNumber(17890252.39415521) \\ should give 18000000
// and so on
```

Comment: please add a complete list of use cases. for easier understanding, remove noise for calling a function to get the value. a single list with two columns are sufficient.

Comment: Why isn't 125 = 100? Can you only round up?

Comment: Updated @NinaScholz

Comment: Yes @AndrewBone, since there will be other numbers between these, I can't round down. If I do, I guess I should always round down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the comparison for multiplier from `10 *` to `100 *` to get a precision of 2 digits before the series of 0s.

```
var roundClosestLegendNumber = function(number) {
    if(number < 10) {
        return number;
    }

    var multiplier = 10;
    while(number >= 100 * multiplier) {
        multiplier = 10 * multiplier;
    }

    count = 1;
    while(number > multiplier * count) {
        count++;
    }

    return multiplier * count;
}
```

Comment: I still think this is not the best solution but it fits my needs best. So I will check this as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: @SühaBoncukçu It clearly isn't a perfect solution, but making the precision dynamic according to the processed set, would prove rather difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You could use significant figures, set sf (I've set mine to 3) then only the first 3 numbers are displayed.

```js
function sigFigure(v) {
  let sf = 3;
  if (v >= Math.pow(10,sf)) {
    let number = v.toPrecision(sf);
    let numbers = number.split("e+")
    return parseInt((numbers[0]*Math.pow(10,numbers[1])).toFixed(0));
  } else {
    return v
  }
}

var array = [0, 945710.38431755, 2268727.9557668166, 14965451.25314727, 17890252.39415521, 3501296406.880383];

console.log(array.map(sigFigure));
```